# Error in fread fwrite in loop - C

Tags: c, loops, fwrite, fread

I have a File IO System, where i store structres
In the code i want to read all the structures one by one and set the variable "pay" as 0 in every structure and write it again in the file

```
long int recsize;
recsize=sizeof(payment);
f=fopen("C:\\HOTEL.DAT", "rb+");
if(f == NULL){
    clrscr();
    cprintf("File could not be opened!");
    sleep(4);
    exit(0);
}

while(fread(&payment, recsize, 1, f) == 1){
            payment.pay=0;
            fseek(f, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&payment, recsize, 1, f);
 }
```

I get a run time error it doesn't change the variable in all the structures it changes it in some of them

Comment: so. where is your question? Explain error

Comment: Please include any compiler errors/warnings, and explain the expected output, and actual output you received.

Comment: @ 555k i have added the error have a look

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have added the error, have a look

Comment: which compiler are you using ? if you use visual studio then this won't work. Your code is correct this will work as Expected with gcc compiler.

Comment: @ Gangadhar I used turbo C++, it didnt work and now i have moved to visual studio, but it shows other errors so i am trying to remove them; then only i would be able to run.
If The code is OK, it should work on turbo C++, why NOT???

Comment: "*... I have added the error ...*": where, please?

Comment: @alk "I get a run time error it doesn't change the variable in all the structures it changes it in some of them" : It means that in turbo C++, when i run the code it doesn't show any compilation error but in run time, it doesn't set all the variables of pay to 0, in the file.
WHICH IT SHOULD HAVE ACCORDING TO THE CODE

Comment: Add debugging statments (`printf()`s) into the source so you'll get an idea where the programm crashes.

Comment: @alk Sir i already did that and i have minimized the code and told you that here is the problem

Comment: IF YOU WANT I CAN PROVIDE YOU WITH THE FULL CODE but the problem is here

Comment: So which line provokes the run-time error?

Comment: @alk it is not as such a runtime error but it is that, it doesnt give the desired output, as I TOLD YOU; It doesnt change all the payment variables to 0 in the file

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not attempting to read your data as a binary blob, and stick to reading individual fields. It's far more robust, especially if you even want to alter your structure

Comment: I am not altering my structure and i have even tried to change it to normal file io but that doesnt help